# ToC formating impossible with Scrivener

Tags: formatting, scrivener, table-of-contents

I want to create a table of contents in Scrivener 2.7 on Mac OS X. I know there is an "Edit > Copy Special > Copy Documents as ToC" command that allows you to paste a static list of links to the copied pages. My problem is that the formatting for the ToC is horribly off and I can't change it.
[image]

If I change the text size, text just gets smaller, formatting stays the same. Deleting spaces before the "??" just causes the number to jump right behind the headline. Caps and newlines go straight back to the position beneath the headline. Spaces are possible but first every single line needs to be individually filled with spaces and second it looks as bad, since distance will still be off for individual numbers by some pixels. And than there is still the problem that it does't even display the page numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to the formatting problem:

1. Mark the ToC link list
2. Go to 'Format > Text > Remove All Tab Stops'
3. Push the page number with tabs to the line end

The '???' is the result of folders that are not documents at the same time, so the reference doesn't find an actual page in the script to refer to.